# How Do I Handle Layout Changes When Orientation Changes?

Tags: android

I am trying to simply alter the setlayout when I rotate my device so that I can have a layout of Views for a particular activity that is suited to the current orientation of the Android device but I am confused about the best way to achieve this.

I have referred to the following android doc:

[Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

I do not need to save any data from my Activity so don't think I really need to use the  onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() method. I tried handling the orientation change myself through the onConfigurationChanged() method, where I find the current orientation then set the layout as required but this results in views that no longer work. Is there something else I need to do in onConfigurationchanged()?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a different view for landscape as opposed to portrait, you would place your layout XML file in both of the following resource folders:

/res/layout - Portrait

/res/layout-land - Landscape

This is, of course, if you have the same views within both, otherwise you may get some NullPointerExceptions.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new directory under res called "res\layout-land", create an .xml layout file in both "res\layout" and "res\layout-land" that have the same name.  For example: "myLayout.xml".  Android will automatically use the layout from the -land directory when in landsacpe orientation and the other when in portrait.

Answer (score 1):

in your projects res folder you should have a layout folder. Create a new folder in the res and call it layout-land. Now create your second set of layout.xml files that are specific to landscape oriented devices. Save them in this layout-land folder. The system will handle the rest for you.

[check out this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) and scroll down to "Providing Alernative Resources" for more detail about different qualifiers you can use on your res folders.

Edit: What device are you using? I created a quick test project that is nothing but hello world but displays different text from a layout stored in res/layout-land folder.
I tried it once with and once without `configChanges="orientation"` in the manifest. When I run the app and switch orientations the layouts behave as expected. The layout from layout-land is displayed when device is landscape and layout from plain layout folder is shown when device is in portrait.

The device I tested on is Sidekick 4g. [Download the test project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5724095/Android%20Apps/OrientationTestZip.zip) and report back how it works on your device if you like.

Comment: Thanks guys, sadly it doesn't seem to work. On orientation change it just keeps the old layout. BTW no new views are added and non are removed, just repositioned. I have to include configChanges="orientation" in the manifest because I do NOT want my activity to restart, is this why I am not seeing the desired result?

Comment: Thanks Tim. I tried it as you originally coded and it does indeed work. However I have realised that it works because Android handles the orientation change. In my own app I override Android when orientation changes because I do not want the Activity restarted. thanks for you help.